# xss_clean removes formatting of tinymce

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, codeigniter-3, xss

In Codeigniter 3.x, if I use `$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);` before saving `$data` to database, it removes all the formatting of **TINYMCE Editor** and places `xss=removed` as below:

```
&lt;span xss=removed&gt;&lt;strong&gt;1. Joint pain &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
```

As a result, I cannot see font colors, background colors, font size change in the output.

If I remove `$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);` before saving `$data` to the database and implement only following security measures, then formatting works fine:

```
$data = trim($data);
//$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
$data = html_escape($data);
$data = strip_tags($data);
```

Now it stores the following in the database:

```
&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: 14pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;1. Joint pain &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
```

I have two questions here:

1. Is the above code sufficient to ensure that the data send to database is fully sanitized and will not allow any attacks. I am using Active Records of Codeigniter for executing SQL.
2. Should I use **xss_clean** while showing output on the screen like this: `echo $this->security->xss_clean(htmlspecialchars_decode($data))`

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The `xss_clean` function in Codeigniter has been removed in newer versions as it was not the right approach. It tried to do too much but not in a reliable way. It can be replaced with either escaping or filtering the input. This is done either with the HTML escape functions, or a library like HTMLPurifier.

HTML escaping is for when the input is plain text, and you want to insert it into an HTML document. In that case, you can escape the data when outputting it on a page. This can depend on the context of where it's inserted (see [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)).

If your input is HTML though, as you get from some editors, then instead you want something like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). This can be applied both before saving the data to the database, and when displaying the data. This filters the HTML against a whitelist of allowed elements, so some formatting can be allowed while preventing scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the response but on the official forum of CI, they say that we should xss clean only when we output the content, we shoudl not do it while saving the content to database. Please check this link: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61933.html

Comment: @ITSagar It depends what cleaning you're doing. Doing `html_escape` multiple times will result in double encoding so should be done once on output. Applying the purifier multiple times though produces the same output as applying it once so it's safe to filter the database values with it. If you want to only run it once, I would do it on output.